# Does Jude 1:9 allude to Zechariah 3:2?

Tags: zechariah, jude

Zechariah 3:2
New International Version

> The LORD said to Satan, "The LORD rebuke you, Satan! **The LORD**, who has chosen Jerusalem, **rebuke you**! Is not this man a burning stick **snatched from the fire**?"

Jude 1:9

> But even the archangel Michael, when he disputed with the devil over the body of Moses, did not presume to bring a slanderous judgment against him, but said, "**The Lord rebuke you**!"

Jude 1:23

> save others by **snatching them from the fire**; and to still others, show mercy tempered with fear, hating even the clothing stained by the flesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a contentious question and has been much debated even from the time of Origen.  According to Origen, the account of Michael disputing with Satan over the body of Moses, is attributed to material contained in the Testament of Moses [also known as, "The Apocalypse of Moses", or, "The Assumption of Moses"].  However, about one third of the text of the Testament of Moses is now missing and there is no mention of such an incident in the text that remains.

Modern critical scholarship (with which I only rarely agree) suggest that this part of Jude is a midrash of Zech 3 and material from the Testament of Moses [eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assumption_of_Moses ].  Certainly, Jude quotes often from both the OT pseudepigrapha, eg, Jude 14, 15 quotes 1 Enoch 1:9.

The idea of the LORD rebuking people is a regular theme in the OT, for example:

- Ps 18:15 - The channels of the sea appeared, and the foundations of the world were exposed, at Your rebuke, O LORD, at the blast of the breath of Your nostrils.
- 1 Sam 22:16 - The channels of the sea appeared, and the foundations of the world were exposed at the rebuke of the LORD, at the blast of the breath of His nostrils.
- Prov 3:11 - My son, do not reject the discipline of the LORD, and do not loathe His rebuke;
- Isa 51:20 - Your sons have fainted; they lie at the head of every street, like an antelope in a net. They are full of the wrath of the LORD, the rebuke of your God.

However, none of these has the LORD rebuking the devil/Satan, so the verbal parallels between Jude and Zech 3 are strong, especially when we include the phrase "snatching from the fire".  However, in the latter case, Zech 3:2 is discussing Jerusalem while Jude 23 is discussing the remnant of the faithful.

Further, two different people are involved: Joshua (the priest in Zech 3) and Moses (the prophet in Jude).  Further, different people are speaking: the LORD speaks in Zech 3:2 and Michael speaks in Jude 9.

Lastly, if we grant that Jude 9 is alluding to Zech 3:2, we have gained little because Zech 3:2 throws no light in Jude.

I think it is safest to conclude that "the LORD rebukes" was a common Hebrew idiom used by Jude to recount what happened at the death of Moses.  On this basis, Zech 3:2 might be using the idiom from the story of Moses; ... but we cannot know for certain.

Answer (score 3):

| #### Jude verses 9,22-23 |
| --- |
| Whereas, Michael, the chief–messenger, when, with the adversary, disputing, he was reasoning about the body of Moses, durst not impose on him a defamatory sentence, but said––The Lord rebuke thee! And, on some, indeed, have mercy,––such as are in doubt, be saving, out of the fire, snatching them ... But, on others, have mercy with fear, hating even, the garment, spotted by the flesh. |
| ###### Emphasized Bible, Rotherham |

The reference being :

| #### Zechariah 3:1-4 |
| --- |
| And he shewed me, Joshua the high priest, standing before the messenger of Yahweh,––and, the Accuser, standing at his right hand, to accuse him. Then said Yahweh unto the Accuser, Yahweh rebuke thee, O Accuser, Yea Yahweh rebuke thee ... ... he who is choosing Jerusalem,––Is not, this, a brand snatched out of the fire? Now, Joshua, was clothed with filthy garments,––though standing before the messenger. Take away the filthy garments from off him; and he said unto him, See! I have caused to pass from off thee, thine iniquity ... |
| ###### Emphasized Bible, Rotherham |

The parallels being :

> '... the body of Moses ...'
>
> '... Joshua the high priest ...'

Joshua being the high priest, and emblematic in the vision, of the priesthood under the law, referred to as "the body of Moses" by Jude (σώματος - Ephesians 4:12).

> '... with the adversary, disputing ...'
>
> '... the Accuser ... to accuse him.'

The accuser or adversary being *satan* in Zechariah and *diabolos* in the LXX and Jude. These terms synonmous with the personification and manifestation of opposition to deity.

> '... Michael, the chief–messenger ...'
>
> '... the messenger of Yahweh ...'

The messenger or angel being *malak Yah-weh* (messenger of the divine) in Zechariah, and *angelos kyrios* (messenger of the lord) in the LXX and *archaggelos* (angel or messenger of the highest rank) in Jude. This Michael being referred to as "one of the chief" angels or messengers (Daniel 10:13).

> 'The Lord rebuke thee!'
>
> 'Yahweh rebuke thee ... Yea Yahweh rebuke thee ...:

Rebuke being *epitimaō* both times in the LXX and *Epitimēsai* in Jude. Obviously *kyrios* in both.

> '... out of the fire, snatching them ...'
>
> '... snatched out of the fire?'

> '... the garment, spotted by the flesh.'
>
> '... clothed with filthy garments ...'

The prophet Zechariah has a vision, of the return of the Babylonian captives to Jerusalem, under Ezra. The particulars of this return being recorded in Ezra (and Nehemiah).

'Now ... **Zechariah** the prophet, a descendant of Iddo, prophesied ... Then ... **Joshua** son of Jozadak set to work ...' (Ezra 5:1-2 NIV)

This **Zechariah**, descendent of Iddo, being the same Zechariah recording the vision :

'... the word of the Lord came to the prophet **Zechariah** son of Berekiah, the son of Iddo ...' (Zechariah 1:1 NIV)

This **Joshua**, son of Jozadak, being the same Joshua referred to in the vision:

'... the high priest, **Joshua** son of Jozadak.' (Zechariah 6:11 NIV)

The return to Jerusalem, being referred to in a metaphor, as a firebrand or "poker", snatched out of the fire of the Babylonian captivity :

> '... he who is choosing Jerusalem,––Is not, this, a brand snatched out of the fire?'

This metaphor of salvation (and subsequent utility in the service of the divine) being employed likewise by Jude :

> 'And, on some, indeed, have mercy,––such as are in doubt, be saving, out of the fire, snatching them ...'

The return to Jerusalem and rebuilding of the temple and the city generally, meeting with significant opposition from within and without :

> 'Despite their fear of the peoples around them ...'
>
> 'Then the peoples around them set out to discourage the people of Judah and make them afraid to go on building. They bribed officials to work against them and frustrate their plans during the entire reign of Cyrus king of Persia and down to the reign of Darius king of Persia.'
>
> 'At the beginning of the reign of Xerxes, they lodged an accusation against the people of Judah and Jerusalem.'
>
> '... they went immediately to the Jews in Jerusalem and compelled them by force to stop.'
>
> 'Thus the work on the house of God in Jerusalem came to a standstill until the second year of the reign of Darius king of Persia.'
>
> (Ezra 3:1, 4:4-5, 6, 23, 24 NIV)

But they were being assisted from on high, the majesty of the heavens having decreed the work would proceed :

> '... to the Jews in Judah and Jerusalem in the name of the God of Israel, who was over them.'
>
> 'But the eye of their God was watching over the elders of the Jews, and they were not stopped ...'
>
> 'So the elders of the Jews continued to build and prosper under the preaching of Haggai the prophet and Zechariah, a descendant of Iddo. They finished building the temple according to the command of the God of Israel and the decrees of Cyrus, Darius and Artaxerxes, kings of Persia.
>
> (Ezra 5:1, 5, 6:14 NIV)

This protection of the workers and assistance in rebuilding the temple from on high (see Daniel 10:13), against the adversaries (hebrew *satan* and greek *diabolos*), being the initial vision and theme in Zechariah's prophecy :

> 'And he shewed me, Joshua the high priest, standing before the messenger of Yahweh,––and, the Accuser, standing at his right hand, to accuse him.'
> 'Then said Yahweh unto the Accuser, Yahweh rebuke thee, O Accuser, Yea Yahweh rebuke thee ...'

Or as Jude puts it :

> 'Whereas, Michael, the chief–messenger, when, with the adversary, disputing, he was reasoning about the body of Moses, durst not impose on him a defamatory sentence, but said––The Lord rebuke thee!'

The account in Ezra informs us :

'Now these are the people of the province who came up from the captivity of the exiles ...'

'And from among the priests ...'

'These searched for their family records, but they could not find them and so were excluded from the priesthood as **unclean**.'

(Ezra 2:1, 61, 62 NIV - the parallel account being found in Nehemiah chapter 7).

This ritual uncleanness being the subject of the subsequent metaphor in Zechariah's prophecy :

> 'Now, Joshua, was clothed with filthy garments,––though standing before the messenger.'

This ritual uncleanness of the priesthood being referenced by Jude also :

> 'But, on others, have mercy with fear, hating even, the garment, spotted by the flesh.'

This saving process, snatching out of the fire of the captivity and ignorance, and sanctifying the priests and the unbeliever, in spite of the difficulty of genealogy or wickedness, being a theme found in both Zechariah and Jude.

Etcetera.

Comment: @davidianwalker I have a question for you in regards to clarity. Are you saying that Michael the arc angel/chief angel is actually "THE" angel of the Lord in the Old Testament?

Comment: @davidianwalker Good, I agree with you that Michael is NOT THE angel of the Lord. And out of curiosity would you agree that THE angel of the Lord in the Old Testament is the preincarnate Jesus Christ? Btw, this I can Biblically prove.

Comment: @ Mr. Bond > What is a "preincarnate Jesus Christ?"

Comment: @davidianwalker It means that Jesus Christ physically appeared in the OT as the angel/messenger of the Lord before He actually incarnated permanently according to John 1:14. If you read John 14:9 Jesus addresses Philip and tells him, "he that hath seen Me hast seen the Father." This does not mean Jesus is God the Father. It means that the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. What is know of the Father is revealed through the Son. John 1:18; 10:30, Colossians 1:15; Hebrews 1:3. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @ Mr. Bond > "It means that Jesus Christ physically appeared in the OT as the angel/messenger of the Lord". I think you should probably go read Matthew 2:1-2 and maybe Luke 2:1-21. Jesus is the guy that lived 2000 years ago and is the central figure in the new testament. He is **promised** in the old testament but that's not the same thing. Obviously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145570/discussion-between-mr-bond-and-davidianwalker).

Comment: @ Mr. Bond > Let's not. Sorry but if you have no understanding of the time span of the old testament then you're probably better off posting a question in that regard. You'll no doubt get some good answers from people who have just started on that journey and eager to share their understanding. Otherwise wikipedia might be a good place to start - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_birth_of_Jesus

Answer (score 0):

I think there is enough parallelism between the two verses to safely conclude that this is a distinct possibility.

What's more, many translations identify the speaker in Zech. 3:2 as the angel of the Lord (or similar).  Consider:

JPS Hebrew-English Tanakh

> But [the angel of] the LORD said to the Accuser

NAB

> And the angel of the LORD said to Satan

TJB

> The angel of Yahweh said to Satan

Others with a similar wording include, but are not limited to:
ERV, GNT, NABRE, NJB, NCB, NWT

Even if a translation doesn't use this wording, like the KJV - I think the context strongly points to the angel of the LORD as the speaker.

There are some large implications if we make this connection, however.  For example, this connection could identify the angel of the LORD as Michael.  I know plenty of folks would disagree with that.

But...as they say, it is what it is.